# How to pin a generic Span<T> instance to work on it with Parallel.For?

Tags: c#, .net, cil, c#-7.2

I'm rewriting some of my extension methods using the new `Span<T>` type and I'm having trouble finding a way to properly pin a generic instance to be able to use parallel code to work on it.

As an example, consider this extension method:

```
public static unsafe void Fill<T>(this Span<T> span, [NotNull] Func<T> provider) where T : struct
{
    int
        cores = Environment.ProcessorCount,
        batch = span.Length / cores,
        mod = span.Length % cores,
        sizeT = Unsafe.SizeOf<T>();
    //fixed (void* p0 = &span.DangerousGetPinnableReference()) // This doesn't work, can't pin a T object
    void* p0 = Unsafe.AsPointer(ref span.DangerousGetPinnableReference());
    {
        byte* p = (byte*)p0; // Local copy for the closure
        Parallel.For(0, cores, i =>
        {
            byte* start = p + i * batch * sizeT;
            for (int j = 0; j < batch; j++)
                Unsafe.Write(start + sizeT * j, provider());
        });

        // Remaining values
        if (mod == 0) return;
        for (int i = span.Length - mod; i < span.Length; i++)
            span[i] = provider();
    }
}
```

Here I just want to fill an input `Span<T>` using some values provider, and since these vectors could be quite large I'd like to populate them in parallel.

> This is just an example, so even if using parallel code here isn't
>   100% necessary, the question still stands, as I'd need to use parallel
>   code again sooner or later anyways.

Now, this code *does work*, but since I'm never actually pinning the input span and given the fact that it could very well be pointing to some managed `T[]` vector, which can be moved around all the time by the GC, I think I might have just been lucky to see it working fine in my tests.

So, my question is:

> Is there any way to pin a generic `Span<T>` instance and get a simple `void*` pointer to it, so that I can pass it around in closures to work on the `Span<T>` instance in parallel code?

Thanks!

Comment: Very important to understand when `Span<T>` can no longer do the job and you have to switch to `Memory<T>`.  Pretty ugly abstraction leak btw, this did not make C# better.  There is a video about it: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Connect/2017/T125

Comment: @HansPassant I know I can't use `Span<T>` in closures, and that's fine for me as I was already going to use pointers for their performance anyways, I'm just looking for a way to pin a `ref T` value (or a `Span<T>`) so that it'd be safe to use a pointer to it without worrying about the GC moving stuff around. Is there any way to achieve that (maybe through `GCHandle` or some other trick)? I mean, I'd still prefer to get a pointer from a `Span<T>` and use it over the actual setter in the span even without the closure problem, for the same performance reason.

Comment: @HansPassant I've opened another related question about pinning a `ref T` variable using an IL method, here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095145/il-method-to-pin-a-ref-t-value-as-void-to-work-on-spant-from-parallel-code Would you mind taking a look at it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I might have found a workaround using one of the new methods in the `Unsafe` class, I've tested it and so far it seems to work. Here it is:

```
public static unsafe void Fill<T>(this Span<T> span, [NotNull] Func<T> provider) where T : struct
{
    int
        cores = Environment.ProcessorCount,
        batch = span.Length / cores,
        mod = span.Length % cores,
        size = Unsafe.SizeOf<T>();
    ref T r0 = ref span.DangerousGetPinnableReference();
    fixed (byte* p0 = &Unsafe.As<T, byte>(ref r0))
    {
        byte* p = p0;
        Parallel.For(0, cores, i =>
        {
            byte* pi = p + i * batch * size;
            for (int j = 0; j < batch; j++, pi += size)
                Unsafe.Write(pi, provider());
        }).AssertCompleted();

        // Remaining values
        if (mod < 1) return;
        for (int i = span.Length - mod; i < span.Length; i++)
            Unsafe.Write(p + i * size, provider());
    }
}
```

Basically, since I can't pin a `ref T` value, I tried to get a `ref byte` variable using `Unsafe.As<T, byte>(ref T value)` and to pin that one instead. Since it points to the same address, I think (hope) it's pinned just fine, it should be doing the same thing in IL.

Comment: You are correct, pinning a variable doesn't depend on its type, just on the address. In fact, CIL even supports `void& pinned` and it works without issues (I have used it to pin a typedref). I guess *Unsafe.As* simply reinterprets the address it receives, so this should work.

Comment: That's awesome, it's great to have found a solution that doesn't actually need an IL implementation, this is just way easier to use (and ship in .NET Standard 2.0 library). Thank you for your help! 