# IL method to pin a ref T value as void* (to work on Span<T> from parallel code)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, cil, c#-7.2

Before the actual question, a small disclaimer:

> This is a related/follow up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083037/how-to-pin-a-generic-spant-instance-to-work-on-it-with-parallel-for?noredirect=1#comment83145811_48083037), but since here I'm talking about a more general issue (how to pin a `ref T` variable to be able to perform pointer operations on it), and I'm proposing a possible (probably wrong) solution, I opened a separate question.

So, the question is: **given a `ref T` variable (assuming it's the first item of an array), how can I pin it so that the GC won't cause problems while working on the underlying array with unsafe pointers?**

I'm not sure this is possible in C# (but I hope I'm wrong), but looking at the IL code for a method that just fixes a `ref int` variable, I tried to come up with a variant that worked on generic types. Here's my idea:

Assume I have this `delegate` in the class "MyTestClass":

```
public unsafe delegate void UnsafeAction(void* p);
```

Then, in IL:

```
.method public hidebysig static void
    Foo<valuetype .ctor (class [netstandard]System.ValueType) T>(
        !!0/*T*/& r, 
        class MyTestClass/UnsafeAction action
    ) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
      [0] void* p,
      [1] !!0/*T*/& pinned V_1
    )

    // Load the ref T argument into the pinned variable (as if fixed were used)
    IL_0000: nop          
    IL_0001: ldarg.0      // r
    IL_0002: stloc.1      // V_1

    // Cast the T* pointer to void*
    IL_0003: ldloc.1      // V_1
    IL_0004: conv.u       
    IL_0005: stloc.0      // p

    // Invoke the action passing the p pointer
    IL_0006: ldarg.1      // action
    IL_0007: ldloc.0      // p
    IL_0008: callvirt     instance void MyTestClass/UnsafeAction::Invoke(void*)
    IL_000d: nop          

    // Set the pinned variable V_1 to NULL
    IL_000e: ldc.i4.0     
    IL_000f: conv.u       
    IL_0010: stloc.1      // V_1
    IL_0011: ret
}
```

The idea would be to be able to use this method like this:

```
public static void Test<T>(this Span<T> span, Func<T> provider)
{
    void Func(void* p)
    {
        // Do stuff with p, possibly in parallel
        // eg. Unsafe.Write(p, provider());
    }
    Foo(ref span.DangerousGetPinnableReference(), Func);
}
```

> Would something like this work? If so, what's the best way to include such a method written in IL into an existing .NET Standard 2.0 project?

Thanks!

**Bonus question**: I've seen the CoreFX repo using ".ilproj" files for projects with IL classes, but they're not actually supported by VS. Is that some extension or do they use their own custom scripts to support that project format? I know there's an [ILProj extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Donny.ILProjVSIX) available, but it isn't either official nor compatible with VS2017.

**Edit**: I might have just had an idea on how to solve this issue, consider this:

```
public static void Foo<T>(ref T value)
{
    fixed (void* p = &Unsafe.As<T, byte>(ref value))
    {
        // Shouldn't the ref T be correctly fixed here, since
        // the "dummy" byte ref had the same address?
    }
}
```

Comment: *I've seen the CoreFX repo using ".ilproj" files for projects with IL classes, but they're not actually supported by VS. Is that some extension or do they use their own custom scripts to support that project format?* If you Google for `ilproj` the top three links will help you out...

Comment: @ta.speot.is Yeah I did that and saw those results, but those extensions don't seem to be official (ie. Not  from MS), and the description of the first one says those project can't be referenced from a C# project, you have to build them and link the dll itself. I was hoping for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, storing the reference in a pinned local is sufficient. During the execution of the method, the referenced memory will not be moved and therefore the pointer will remain valid.

You can also remove the `nop`s from your method (the result of analyzing code compiled under Debug), and setting the variable to zero afterwards is also unnecessary, because the method exits just after it.

As for how to distribute the CIL code with a C# project, I would use *DynamicMethod*, but I don't know if that is available in .NET Standard. If not, compiling the IL to a `.dll` or `.netmodule` and referencing it or automatically linking it to the main project is not such a big issue.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I left those `nop`s as I wasn't sure if they were for alignment or just leftovers from the debug mode, good to hear I can remove them. Unfortunately `DynamicMethod` isn't there on .NET Standard 2.0, I'll try to figure out how to properly get a dll from an .il file. Also, looking at the question and that code, do you think this is the right approach here and the only possible solution, or there might be another, easier way to achieve this?

Comment: @Sergio0694 `ilasm /dll` should work, and if you remove the `.assembly` section, it would also create a `.netmodule`. I don't work often with `Span<T>`, so I don't know if there is a better solution to your underlying problem. However, the method you have created is similar to what I was using in my library ([here](https://github.com/IllidanS4/SharpUtils/blob/master/Reference.cs#L114)). The only difference is that I have separated the conversion to pointer from the pinning.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, that repo looks great! I'm not seeing a NuGet link, so if you haven't already, you should definitely consider publishing your library over there too!

Comment: Thanks! I have been already suggested to publish it on NuGet, and I'd love to, but I would like to split the library into smaller coherent packages before that.

Comment: That's a good idea. Also, I think I've just had an idea on how to solve this issue using existing APIs, would you mind taking a look at my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48105559/3813976 and on the edit at the bottom of this question too, and let me know what you think?